# Python Concurrent logging read

Tags: python, locking, multiprocessing

I've been using *ConcurrentLogHandler* for multi-platform/multi-processes file logging.

Now I'd like to be sure I'm reading 'atomic' parts of the logs, that is I do not want to read half a log line for example. The concurrent file logger actually performs a *LOCK_EX* (exclusive) on the file, did anyone has a practice of using *LOCK_SH* (shared) on the *ConcurrentLogHandler* files? I cannot see such a read in the module services.

Or do you have such an experience in such a multiple-read/single-write using another python module? (without coding again everything by hand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConcurrentLogHandler` is just using the file locking tools the OS provides (`fcntl.flock` on Posix, `win32file.LockFileEx` on Windows), so there shouldn't be any issues if you take a `LOCK_SH` on the file; `ConcurrentLogHandler` will respect the lock when it tries taking its `LOCK_EX`. The easiest way to do it would be to use the [`portalocker` module](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~lowell-alleman/python-concurrent-log-handler/master/view/head:/src/portalocker.py) that's included with `ConcurrentLogHandler`:

```
import portalocker

with open("logfile.txt") as f:
    portalocker.lock(f, portalocker.LOCK_SH)
    for line in f:
        # do stuff with each line
# file will be unlocked when its closed.
```

Comment: ok, I'll have a try, it looks to me there were some other hiddent locks in the log Handlers, but you're right, it would be queued at least for the protalocker actual lock. thx